# svm CUSTOM KERNEL PYTHON ERROR

Tags: python, kernel, svm

I am trying to make a custom kernel in python. This is my code :

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm

from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import pylab as pl 
import math

digits = datasets.load_digits()


X = digits.data[:-200]

Y = digits.target[:-200]



def kernal6(x,y):
    d=np.linalg.norm(x-y)
    Xn=np.linalg.norm(x)
    Yn=np.linalg.norm(y)
    return (Xn+Yn-d)/np.sqrt(Xn*Yn)    


clf5 = svm.SVC(kernel=kernal6)
clf5.fit(X,Y)
```

but I keep getting this error :

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the wrong value. The kernel function should return a matrix. Have a look at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html) to see an example of a proper kernel function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X = digits.data[:-200, :2]  #You were doing this wrong too
Y = digits.target[:-200]

def my_kernel(x, y):
    M = np.array([[2, 0], [0, 1.0]])
    return np.dot(np.dot(x, M), y.T) #returns a matrix

def kernal6(x,y):
    d=np.linalg.norm(x-y)
    Xn=np.linalg.norm(x)
    Yn=np.linalg.norm(y)
    return (Xn+Yn-d)/np.sqrt(Xn*Yn) #returns a float    

print "Testing SVC with my_kernel"
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
clf.fit(X, Y) #works fine
print "Success!"

print "Testing kernal6"
print "kernal6 direct call:",kernal6(X, X) #will return a result
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=kernal6)
try:
    clf.fit(X, Y)#fails
except:
    print "Failed to fit with kernal6"
```

Comment: No, try again...run the code in my edit and observe the output

Comment: you're making a bad assumption. Have a look at the [numpy.dot documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). The sklearn example applies it to a multidimensional array therefore it returns a multidimensional array, which is the type of value the SVC expects to get back from a call to the kernel function

Comment: I've updated the answer again. And I never said my code fixes your error, only that I'm showing you why you are getting the error. I call the sklearn custom kernel example, and yours, just to show that while your kernel function does execute, the return value is not what the `SVC` is expecting

Answer (score 0):

IndexError means that you are trying to access an array/tuple's value of an index that is not defined. The only time where you try to access a tuple (it says **tuple** index out of range) is when you declare `X` and `Y`. Therefore, it must be a problem with the slicing notation. I think that the reason is because the tuple does not have more or equal than 200 elements (the array[:-200] returns len(array) - 200, which may be a negative integer again); however, I cannot run your code because my interpreter throws an error, so I am sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: I tried to change that to :X = digits.data

Y = digits.target  but I still have the same problem. I tried this also for other kernel but the problem still persist.

Comment: Steve, I think that I need the line number to debug. Can you figure out the line number, or can you just use divide-and-conquer?